# How can i use the functions in "test.clj" automatically once entering the REPL?

Tags: clojure

In haskell, i can use the functions defined in "test.hs" automatically when entering its interactive environment by cusomizing ~/.ghci .

```
>cat ~/.ghci
:def hoogle \str -> return $ ":! hoogle --count=15 \"" ++ str ++ "\""
:cd /media/E/www/qachina/db/doc/test
:load test
```

Now i convert "test.hs" to "test.clj" and use the following script to enter its REPL.

```
%cat ~/bin/myclj 
#!/bin/sh
breakchars="(){}[],^%$#@\"\";:''|\\"
CLOJURE_DIR=/usr/share/clojure
CLOJURE_JAR="$CLOJURE_DIR"/clojure.jar
CONTRIB_JAR="$CLOJURE_DIR"/clojure-contrib.jar
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then 
     exec rlwrap --remember -c -b "$breakchars" \
       -f "$HOME"/.clj_completions \
     java -cp "$CLOJURE_JAR:$CONTRIB_JAR" clojure.main
else
     exec java -cp "$CLOJURE_JAR:$CONTRIB_JAR" clojure.main $1 -- "$@"
fi
```

Sincerely!

Comment: So what is the actual question?

Comment: The question is "how can i use the functions in test.clj file" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for evaluation + REPL you can use following command:

```
java -cp .....  clojure.main -i script/run.clj -r
```

See [documentation for clojure.main](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.main-api.html#clojure.main/main) function. Order of command line options is important!

Comment: If you want to use command-line editing functionality, you can add JLine library to CLASSPATH and put `jline.ConsoleRunner` before `clojure.main`... See example at https://github.com/liebke/incanter/blob/master/script/repl (although there are some problems with non-latin1 characters in JLine)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use Leiningen.

```
 lein new foo
```

Paste your code into ./foo/src/foo/core.clj and run 'lein repl' in ./foo

That way you can use the functions defined in core.clj in a REPL.